# Where is the fifteenth watermelon?

Tags: ios, angry-birds-rio

In Angry Birds Rio, I can't seem to find the fifteenth watermelon; where is it hiding?

I'm on my iPhone if that helps. I've found the ones on the following levels:

> 5-5, 5-11, 5-13, 5-14, 5-15, 6-2, 6-3,
>  6-4, 6-5, 6-6, 6-7, 6-9, 6-12, 6-14

Comment: @weslei ~ Thanks, new to this community :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this one is "invisble" on the iPhone (but it appears to be visible on other platforms from anecdotal evidence)

The remaining one is on 5-2, triggered by hitting the TNT box to the far right of the screen, past the umbrella and water ring. This causes a new box on a chain to fall from the sky.

(self-answer due to this one was tricky for me and I couldn't find it for a long time -- 3 stars on all the levels before I found this one!)

Comment: On Android, you hit the TNT box on the far right which releases a box swinging from above out of view.  The watermelon is inside that second box.

Comment: @MatthewRead you're right, I didn't put all the steps. I wanted to tell people where to find the "trigger". I need to edit my answer. (also, thanks for proving the anecdotal "proof" of the location)